# Reading from a CSV file into Objects

Tags: java, arrays, csv, arraylist, nosuchelementexception

I need help reading from a file:
my file looks exactly like that:

```
2,
Bob,
1,
Hand, 10.0, Broken,
John,
Leg, 20.0, Broken,
Hand, 10.0, Broken, //this comma has to be here
```

I need to load this data into array where Bob and John is stored, and injuries into
arrayLists.

Default patient constructor creates arrayList for each of them.

My code looks like that:

```
public void load(File f) {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new File Reader(f));
        String nextLine = br.readLine();
        while (nextLine!=null) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(nextLine, ",");
        int numberOfPatients = Integer.praseInt(st.nextToken());

        for (int j=0 j<numberOfPatients; j++) {
            String name = st.nextToken();   // This is the place where I get NoSuchElementException
            int age = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            this.patients[j-1] = new Patient(name,age);
            int numberOfInjuries = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

            for (int i=0; i<numberOfInjuries-1; i++) {
                String type = (st.nextToken());

                if (type.equals("Leg")) {
                    int cost = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    String injury = st.nextToken();
                    // addInjury - function to add new injury to the arrayList
                    this.patients[j].addInjury(new Leg(cost, injury));
                } else if (type.equals("Hand")) {
                    int cost = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    String injury = st.nextToken();
                    this.patients[j].addInjury(new Hand(cost, injury);
                }
            nextLine = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

It returns java.util.NoSuchElementException.
If anyone could help me I would appreciate it! thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that `bufferedReader` works is that each line is parsed separately. That's what you are doing at  `String nextLine = br.readLine()` - reading in a new line each time.

With your CSV file, you've only read in the first line - `2,`. The reason you are getting a `NoSuchElementException` is that there is nothing else on that first line. The tokenizer cannot find anything else for the current string. You'll either have to change how you parse the input, or read in the next line before continuing.

Comment: Also, with how your for loop is setup, you'll be trying to access patients[j-1]. With j (initially) 0, you'll be trying to access patients[-1], which will break. Hope this helps

Comment: Should I add nextLine = br.readLine(); whenever I want to skip to a next line then?

Comment: That will work, but you run the risk of nextLine being null (especially if you were dealing with an unknown set of data). Just make sure you check it before using it.

Comment: it is still not working, throw out the same error :/ isin't there something else I am missing in the code?

Answer (score 1):

Syntax errors:

```
Integer.praseInt(st.nextToken());
```

....should be **`parse`**

```
for (int j=0 ....
```

missing **`;`**